# Calculate the growth ratio from first value in every column in a pandas dataframe and return a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

need a bit of help with my function.

This is what I'm trying to do:

Build a predictive model that can give us the best guess at what the population growth rate in a given year might be. We will calculate the population growth rate as follows:

As such, we can only calculate the growth rate for the year 1961 onwards.

Write a function that takes the population_df and a country_code as input and computes the population growth rate for a given country starting from the year 1961. This function must return a return a 2-d numpy array that contains the year and corresponding growth rate for the country.

Function Specifications:

Should take a population_df and country_code string as input and return a numpy array as output.
The array should only have two columns containing the year and the population growth rate, in other words, it should have a shape (?, 2) where ? is the length of the data.

ℎ_ = __ − __ / __

Should take a population_df and country_code string as input and return a numpy array as output.
The array should only have two columns containing the year and the population growth rate, in other words, it should have a shape (?, 2) where ? is the length of the data.

Input DF head:
[image: population_df]

My code:(Changeable)

```
def pop_growth_by_country_year(df,country_code):
    country_data = df.loc[country_code]
    for columnName, columnData in country_data.iteritems():
        country_data = ((country_data[columnData] - country_data[columnData-1]) / country_data[columnData-1])
    output = country_data.reset_index().to_numpy().reshape(-1, 2)
    return output
```

Input function(Not changeable)

```
pop_growth_by_country_year(population_df,'ABW')
```

Expected output:

```
array([[ 1.961e+03,  2.263e-02],
       [ 1.962e+03,  1.420e-02],
       [ 1.963e+03,  8.360e-03],
       [ 1.964e+03,  5.940e-03],
            ...       ....
       [ 2.015e+03,  5.260e-03],
       [ 2.016e+03,  4.610e-03],
       [ 2.017e+03,  4.220e-03]])
```

Comment: can you provide the output of `population_df.iloc[:,:15].to_dict()`?

Comment: '''
{'1960': {'ABW': 54211.0,
  'AFG': 8996351.0,
  'AGO': 5643182.0,
  'ALB': 1608800.0,
  'AND': 13411.0,
  'ARE': 92634.0,
  'ARG': 20619075.0,
  'ARM': 1874120.0,
  'ASM': 20013.0,
  'ATG': 55339.0,
  'AUS': 10276477.0,
  'AUT': 7047539.0,
  'AZE': 3895396.0,
'''

Comment: I can read only the first year from this `dict`. Try `population_df.iloc[:5,:10].to_dict()`

Comment: {'1960': {'ABW': 54211.0,
  'AFG': 8996351.0,
  'AGO': 5643182.0,
  'ALB': 1608800.0,
  'AND': 13411.0},
 '1961': {'ABW': 55438.0,
  'AFG': 9166764.0,
  'AGO': 5753024.0,
  'ALB': 1659800.0,
  'AND': 14375.0},
 '1962': {'ABW': 56225.0,
  'AFG': 9345868.0,
  'AGO': 5866061.0,
  'ALB': 1711319.0,
  'AND': 15370.0},
 '1963': {'ABW': 56695.0,
  'AFG': 9533954.0,
  'AGO': 5980417.0,
  'ALB': 1762621.0,
  'AND': 16412.0},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My input:

```
population_df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1960': {'ABW': 54211.0, 'AFG': 8996351.0, 'AGO': 5643182.0, 'ALB': 1608800.0, 'AND': 13411.0},
    '1961': {'ABW': 55438.0, 'AFG': 9166764.0, 'AGO': 5753024.0, 'ALB': 1659800.0, 'AND': 14375.0},
    '1962': {'ABW': 56225.0, 'AFG': 9345868.0, 'AGO': 5866061.0, 'ALB': 1711319.0, 'AND': 15370.0},
    '1963': {'ABW': 56695.0, 'AFG': 9533954.0, 'AGO': 5980417.0, 'ALB': 1762621.0, 'AND': 16412.0}
})
population_df
```

My solution:

```
def pop_growth_by_country_year(df,country_code):
    current_population = df.loc[country_code]
    previous_population = current_population.shift(1)
    growth = (current_population-previous_population)/previous_population
    return growth.dropna().reset_index().astype(float).values
```

Output of `pop_growth_by_country_year(population_df,'ABW')`

```
array([[1.96100000e+03, 2.26337828e-02],
       [1.96200000e+03, 1.41960388e-02],
       [1.96300000e+03, 8.35927079e-03]])
```

Note that, since you don't have the previous population for the first year (1960 in this case), you will miss the growth for that year and for this reason `len(output)=len(input)-1`

Comment: You welcome. Enjoy working with pandas and numpy :)